# Create radius line and label the length to a buffer geometry generated

Tags: qgis, labeling, buffer, geometry-generator, qgis-expression

From a point geometry layer, I'm using an expression with buffer function as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

I would like to add two more expressions to this point geometry layer:

1. An expression for Symbology to draw the radius line
2. An expression for Labels to add the length value of the radius

The expression that creates the buffer is as follows:

```
buffer(
    $geometry,
    array_mean(  -- lengths mean
        array_foreach(
            overlay_nearest( -- get nearest points
                'POINT_LAYER',
                $geometry,
                limit:=4
            ),
            length(
                make_line(
                    $geometry,
                    @element
                )
            )
        )
    )   
)
```

I show a screenshot with the expected result:

[image]

Comment: So you seem to know, how to generate geometries using expression. What is keeping you from using `make_line()`?

Comment: I have made an approximation with this expression but I think it is not the correct solution. I think the hard part is to get a line to the edge of the buffer:


shortest_line ( 
    collect_geometries ( 
        overlay_nearest( -- get nearest points
                'BUFFER',
                $geometry,
    --max_distance:=1000,
                limit:=4
            )
    ),
    $geometry
)

Comment: The result that appears in the screen capture of the expected result is a hand-drawn simulation. It is not the application of the shortest line function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the radial line (a *Geometry Generator* symbol layer):

```
with_variable(
    'buffer_dist',           -- store result of distance calculation as a variable
    array_mean( -- lengths mean 
        array_foreach( 
            overlay_nearest( -- get nearest points 
                @layer, 
                $geometry, 
                limit:=4 
            ), 
            length( 
                make_line( 
                    $geometry, @element 
                ) 
            ) 
        )
    ),
        
    make_line(
        $geometry,
        project(
            $geometry,
            @buffer_dist,   -- insert the calculated value as a variable
            radians(270)
        )
    )
)
```

For the label position (*Geometry Generator* placement):

```
with_variable(
    'buffer_dist',
    array_mean( -- lengths mean 
        array_foreach( 
            overlay_nearest( -- get nearest points 
                @layer, 
                $geometry, 
                limit:=4 
            ), 
            length( 
                make_line( 
                    $geometry, @element 
                ) 
            ) 
        )
    ),
        
    project(
        $geometry,
        @buffer_dist / 2,      
        radians(270)
    )
)
```

The label expression:

```
array_mean( -- lengths mean 
        array_foreach( 
            overlay_nearest( -- get nearest points 
                @layer, 
                $geometry, 
                limit:=4 
            ), 
            length( 
                make_line( 
                    $geometry, @element 
                ) 
            ) 
        )
    )
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Matt, I confirm that this solution is pretty close to what I am looking for. However, this solution is designed to be applied to a polygon geometry. Could be develop an expression that works for a point geometry to which the buffer function is applied?

Comment: You have an attribute field that determines the buffer distance in the point layer?

Comment: No. The attribute is calculated 'on-the-fly' using the following expression developed by Kadir Şahbaz:


buffer(
    $geometry,
    array_mean(  -- lengths mean
        array_foreach(
            overlay_nearest( -- get nearest points
                'gg',
                $geometry,
                limit:=4
            ),
            length(
                make_line(
                    $geometry,
                    @element
                )
            )
        )
    )   
)

Comment: See update. I store the result of Kadir's expression as a variable and then use it to create the line and to position the label.

Comment: Please include important information, like the fact the buffers are created 'on-the-fly', and the expression to do so, in your question, rather than added as comments. It's clearer when all the essential details are in one place.

Comment: Yes, of course.
Now the Symbology of radius line and the Placement of Label it is working correctly. However, when I enter the function for the label text: round(bounds_width($geometry) / 2, 2)
the returned value is 0

Comment: A point has no extent, hence 0 bounds @Acperience

Comment: OK, I understand that with this solution, now it does not make sense to use the function round(bounds_width($geometry) / 2, 2) to label tex radius. Could be compatible this final solution that works correctly with labeling the radius line length?

Comment: No, hence I removed it from my answer. The label expression is essentially the expression of Kadir, without the buffering part. I have added it above.